# Trouble with Encodable Trait Bounds on Enums and Structs

Tags: rust

Taking Rust for a Test Drive.  Fun so far, but I'm uncertain how to set up trait bounds in this instance to do something useful.

> Failed to find an implementation of trait
>   serialize::serialize::Encodable,std::io::IoError>
>   for T

It seems to me that I need to set up a bound on the enumeration `List<T: Encodable>`.  However, the compiler gets a bit upset when I try this.

> error: trait bounds are not allowed in enumeration
>   definitions

So I assumed that I would have to put the bounds on the implementation `impl<T:Encodable>`, but got this...

> error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2 but
>   found 0

If that's the case, how would I do something like this in Rust?

```
extern crate serialize;
use serialize::{ json, Encodable };

#[deriving(Decodable, Encodable)] 
pub enum List<T> {
    Node(T, Box<List<T>>),
    Nil
}

impl<T> List<T> {
fn to_json(&self) -> String {
    json::Encoder::str_encode(self)
}
}
```

Seems to work fine when I work don't try to encapsulate the encoding, since it knows that int is encodable...

```
let mut list: List<int> = Nil;
...
let encoded_string = json::Encoder::str_encode(&list);
println!("{}", encoded_string);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, bounds cannot be placed on structs and enums. This may change, but until then, the `impl` is the place you define those constraints.

Let’s look at the definition of the trait: [`Encodable<S: Encoder<E>, E>`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/serialize/trait.Encodable.html). `S` and `E` are the things it is complaining about, wanting you to define them.

Now let’s take a look at what `#[deriving(Encodable)]` does, by compiling the code with `rustc --pretty expanded`, which expands that attribute.

```
#![feature(phase)]
#![no_std]
#![feature(globs)]
#[phase(plugin, link)]
extern crate std = "std#0.11.0-pre";
extern crate native = "native#0.11.0-pre";
extern crate serialize;
use std::prelude::*;
use serialize::{json, Encodable};

pub enum List<T> { Node(T, Box<List<T>>), Nil, }
#[automatically_derived]
impl <__S: ::serialize::Encoder<__E>, __E,
      T: ::serialize::Encodable<__S, __E>> ::serialize::Encodable<__S, __E>
     for List<T> {
    fn encode(&self, __arg_0: &mut __S) -> ::std::result::Result<(), __E> {
        match *self {
            Node(ref __self_0, ref __self_1) => {
                let _e = __arg_0;
                _e.emit_enum("List",
                             |_e|
                                 _e.emit_enum_variant("Node", 0u, 2u, |_e| {
                                                      match _e.emit_enum_variant_arg(0u,
                                                                                     |_e|
                                                                                         (*__self_0).encode(_e))
                                                          {
                                                          Ok(__try_var) =>
                                                          __try_var,
                                                          Err(__try_var) =>
                                                          return Err(__try_var)
                                                      };
                                                      return _e.emit_enum_variant_arg(1u,
                                                                                      |_e|
                                                                                          (*__self_1).encode(_e));
                                                  }))
            },
            Nil => {
                let _e = __arg_0;
                _e.emit_enum("List",
                             |_e|
                                 _e.emit_enum_variant("Nil", 1u, 0u, |_e| {
                                                      return ::std::result::Ok(());
                                                  }))
            }
        }
    }
}
#[automatically_derived]
impl <__D: ::serialize::Decoder<__E>, __E,
      T: ::serialize::Decodable<__D, __E>> ::serialize::Decodable<__D, __E>
     for List<T> {
    fn decode(__arg_0: &mut __D) -> ::std::result::Result<List<T>, __E> {
        __arg_0.read_enum("List",
                          |_d|
                              _d.read_enum_variant(["Node", "Nil"],
                                                   |_d, i|
                                                       ::std::result::Ok(match i
                                                                             {
                                                                             0u
                                                                             =>
                                                                             Node(match _d.read_enum_variant_arg(0u,
                                                                                                                 |_d|
                                                                                                                     ::serialize::Decodable::decode(_d))
                                                                                      {
                                                                                      Ok(__try_var)
                                                                                      =>
                                                                                      __try_var,
                                                                                      Err(__try_var)
                                                                                      =>
                                                                                      return Err(__try_var)
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  match _d.read_enum_variant_arg(1u,
                                                                                                                 |_d|
                                                                                                                     ::serialize::Decodable::decode(_d))
                                                                                      {
                                                                                      Ok(__try_var)
                                                                                      =>
                                                                                      __try_var,
                                                                                      Err(__try_var)
                                                                                      =>
                                                                                      return Err(__try_var)
                                                                                  }),
                                                                             1u
                                                                             =>
                                                                             Nil,
                                                                             _
                                                                             =>
                                                                             ::std::rt::begin_unwind("internal error: entered unreachable code",
                                                                                                     "s.rs",
                                                                                                     4u)
                                                                         })))
    }
}

impl <T> List<T> {
    fn to_json(&self) -> String { json::Encoder::str_encode(self) }
}
```

Yes, this is messy. But it shows the `Encodable` implementation and the bounds that are being written. Basically, the constraints are expected to be written by you in the same way: you don’t care about any *specific* types, just that you have an encoder. This, then, is what it boils down to:

```
impl<S: Encoder<E>, E, T: Encodable<S, E>> Encodable<S, E> for List<T> {
    fn encode(&self, encoder: &mut S) -> Result<(), E> {
        …
    }
}
```